# Bourbon neat multiple breakpoints

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, bourbon, neat

I know following can be done in bourbon neat:

```
$mobile: new-breakpoint(max-width: 320px);
$tablet: new-breakpoint(max-width:760px min-width:321px);
$desktop: new-breakpoint(min-width: 761px);
```

then I can do something like this:

```
@include media($mobile) {
    // some styling
}
```

It works great. Now I have to add styles that affects mobile and tablet. I am looking for union of mobile and tablet breakpoint.

```
//desired behavior 
//I know this is not available. Just made up
@include media($mobile, $tablet) {
    // some styling.
    // this should be applied to mobile and tablet
}
```

Comment: Isn't just specifying $tablet enough, $tablet encompasses $mobile, according to your break-point definitions.

Comment: I am sorry; I forgot to mention min-width on tablet breakpoint. There is min-width breakpoint on tablet.

Comment: What is the point of doing this, media queries take very little space anyway. You might save two lines, but you will more likely add lines.

Comment: Do you mean that I should add a new breakpoint? I can do that but I was thinking if there was a way to specify 2 breakpoints together and it knows how to merge them.

Comment: What's the point of putting breakpoints in variables? You should just specify all the breakpoints you want the normal way. I can see maybe wanting to put the styles they contain in vars, but the breakpoints themselves, I don't really get the point.

Comment: Dude, its helpful. If for some reason, I need to change some pixels around breakpoints, I don't have to deal with changing them everywhere on stylesheets. Thats the basic explanation for using any variable.

Comment: @watson why use SASS at all?! DRY is the reason for using a variable.. anyway I need this multiple target stuff too. this is not a dumb question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if anyone is still needing this but I made a following function:

```
@mixin multiple-media($media...) {
  @each $query in $media {
    @include media($query) {
      @content
    }
  }
}
```

that works for me just fine.

```
@include multiple-media($mobile-landscape, $tablet-portrait, $tablet-landscape, $laptop, $desktop) {
  .mobile {
    @include display(none);
  }
}
```

Produces

```
@media screen and (min-width: 29.25em) and (max-width: 48em) and (max-height: 29.25em) {
  .logo a .mobile {
    display: none; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 29.25em) and (max-width: 50em) and (min-height: 29.25em) {
  .logo a .mobile {
    display: none; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) and (max-width: 80em) and (max-height: 50em) {
  .logo a .mobile {
    display: none; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 80em) and (max-width: 105em) {
  .logo a .mobile {
    display: none; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 105em) {
  .logo a .mobile {
    display: none; } }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to target mobile and tablet for a specific style, I think your best option would be create a new breakpoint:

```
$mobile-to-tablet: new-breakpoint(max-width:760px min-width:321px $cols);
```

And add under this breakpoint all your specific css.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Bourbon-related answer, but anyway.

There's a [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) extension that does exactly what you want: [Breakpoint Slicer](https://github.com/lolmaus/breakpoint-slicer#readme).

You just set up your breakpoints like this:

```
$slicer-breakpoints: 0 320px 760px;
// Slices:           | 1 |  2  |  3  →
```

And then just address the gaps between breakpoints (called "slices") with the short `at`, `from`, `to` and `between` mixins. For example, `@include at(2)` will set a `min-width: 320px, max-width: 760px` media query.

With the ecosystem of numerous powerful Compass extension there's really no reason to go drunk with Bourbon. For a powerful semantic grid, use [Singularity](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity#readme), it integrates well with [Breakpoint](http://breakpoint-sass.com/) and Breakpoint Slicer.